# delete element from xml using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I've a xml file like:

```
<starting>
   <start>
      <site>mushfiq.com</site>
      <site>mee.con</site>
      <site>ttttt.co</site>
      <site>jkjhkhjkh</site>
      <site>jhkhjkjhkhjkhjkjhkh</site>
     <site>dasdasdasdasdasdas</site>
 </start>
</starting>
```

Now I need to delete any `<site>...</site>` and value will randomly be given from a textbox.

Here is my code :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"AddedSites.xml");                
var deleteQuery = from r in doc.Descendants("start") where r.Element("site").Value == txt.Text.Trim() select r;
foreach (var qry in deleteQuery)
{
    qry.Element("site").Remove();
}
doc.Save(@"AddedSites.xml");
```

If I put the value of first element in the textbox then it can delete it, but if I put any value of element except the first element's value it could not able to delete! I need I'll put any value of any element...as it can be 2nd element or 3rd or 4th and so on.... can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, with further editing, it's clearer what you want to do, and as it happens it's significantly easier than you're making it, thanks to the [`Remove` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357554.aspx) on `IEnumerable<T> where T : XNode`:

```
string target = txt.Text.Trim();
doc.Descendants("start")
   .Elements("site")
   .Where(x => x.Value == target)
   .Remove();
```

That's all you need.

Comment: deleteQuery is returing an empty list when it is not given the first element's value in textbox

Comment: @Shishir: See my edit. While your code is using completely different names from your sample XML, and you haven't explained what you really want to happen, it's very hard to help you.

Comment: @Shishir: It's somewhat better now, but you haven't shown a `domain` element to remove. You're making it very hard to help you.

Comment: thanks a lot ...I've updated my question. it will be qry.Element("site").Remove()

Comment: @Shishir: Having edited your question (you should *really* look at the preview) it's getting a bit clearer... although you haven't helped yourself by being so vague.

Comment: @Shishir: Have a look yet again. (All of this could have been done the first time if you'd made your question clear to start with.)