# C# LINQ Query to filter(delete) node by date

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ and wanted to write a C# LINQ query to filter nodes on a XDocument Object. How would I filter based on a date Value from within a tag, in this case the  tag. I want to loop and create a new XDocument object with the filtered results by Date.

XDocument :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BMW>
<Model>
    <Desc>335</Desc>
    <ReleaseDate>6/20/2016</ReleaseDate>
    <Engine>V6</Engine>
    <BodyStyle></BodyStyle>
</Model>
<Model>
    <Desc>550</Desc>
    <ReleaseDate>7/12/2016</ReleaseDate>
    <Engine>V6</Engine>
    <BodyStyle></BodyStyle>
</Model>
<Model>
    <Desc>750</Desc>
    <ReleaseDate>8/26/2016</ReleaseDate>
    <Engine>V8</Engine>
    <BodyStyle>Executive Sedan</BodyStyle>
</Model>
</BMW>
```

Here's my method signature

```
    private XDocument FilterByDate(XDocument xDoc, DateTime filterDate)
    {

    }
```

My Output :

If I pass the datetime value of 08/26/2016. I should essentially get back a XDocument with the the last ModelTag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BMW>    
<Model>
    <Desc>750</Desc>
    <ReleaseDate>8/26/2016</ReleaseDate>
    <Engine>V8</Engine>
    <BodyStyle>Executive Sedan</BodyStyle>
</Model>
</BMW>
```

Comment: Follow the example \ solution in this response here, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483452/delete-element-from-xml-using-linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would filter your model.

```
var model = xDoc.Descendants("Model")
    .Where(m => m.Element("ReleaseDate").Value == filterDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

That will return an `XElement`.  You can make your new doc with that element.

- If you want a list of matches, then use `.ToList()` instead of `.FirstOrDefault()`
- if you want to remove everything that's not a match, then you can negate the condition, by changing `==` to `!=`, and you add `.Remove()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`, and of course, not assigning the "result" to a variable

Comment: wow. Thank you for the explaining the combination of operators to tweak the results. worked for me!